# How to copy one google sheet to different another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I do have two different google sheet, I need to copy say sheet Test from one to another using script, but getting error, any thought on this?

```
   var source_sheet= "https://address of the otgoogle sheet tho be copied over")"

  //here I'm on another google sheet, add a menu to copy the source from above
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
 //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var result = ui.prompt(      
  'Add New Sheet',
  'Please enter Name',
  ui.ButtonSet.OK);         

  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.copyTo(link_to_src).setName(text);
```

Getting below error:
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo. (line xx, file "copy-rename")DetailsDismiss

Any help will be appreciated in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to copy a sheet of the source Spreadsheet, which is not the active Spreadsheet to the active Spreadsheet, which run the script.
- `source_sheet` is the URL of Spreadsheet like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit`.
- When you run the script, you want to input the sheet name in source Spreadsheet using a dialog and copy the sheet to the active Spreadsheet.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script

Please modify your script as follows. Before you run the script, please set the destination Spreadsheet URL to `source_sheet`.

From:

```
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
sheet.copyTo(link_to_src).setName(text);
```

To:

```
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(source_sheet).getSheetByName(text);
if (sourceSheet) {
  sourceSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(text).activate();
} else {
  ui.alert(text + " sheet was not found.");
}
```

- When you run the script, a dialog is opened. When a sheet name of the source Spreadsheet is inputted, the sheet is copied to the current active Spreadsheet, then, the copied sheet is activated.
- If the sheet name which is not included in the source Spreadsheet is inputted, a dialog is opened.

#### References:

- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you so much, your modified code copies the local to remote sheet, what I want to do is to copy the remote file/sheet into the active local one...Hope that is clear Thanks again

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience because of my poor English skill. I added one more modification point. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal again, I have to apologize.

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize again. About `copy one of he sheet in file-1 to file-2`, my initial answer is the modification for achieving it. Can I ask you about the issue of my initial answer?

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. You want to copy a sheet of the Spreadsheet, which is not the active Spreadsheet to the active Spreadsheet, which run the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I could understand about your goal. In this case, the sheet name of the source Spreadsheet is inputted by the prompt of `Add New Sheet`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding. You want to copy a sheet of the source Spreadsheet to the active Spreadsheet. At that time, you want to copy the same sheet name with the active sheet and rename the copied sheet by the inputted name. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. You want to copy a sheet of the Spreadsheet, which is not the active Spreadsheet to the active Spreadsheet, which run the script. And the sheet name of the source Spreadsheet is inputted by the prompt of `Add New Sheet`. For this, you said "Yes". I cannot understand about the difference between this and your latest replying. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this. Can you explain about the detail?

Comment: @user2912312 You want to overwrite the current active sheet with a sheet in the source Spreadsheet. And the sheet name of source and destination is the same. Then, you want to rename the sheet name with the inputted text. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding and poor English skill. About `How to copy the source into destination as a new sheet`, you want to copy the current sheet as new Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? In this case, the sheet is the current sheet or all sheets in the active Spreadsheet?

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying. About `copy the source from openByUrl() to active sheet`, the latest script is the script for achieving it. Can I ask you about the difference between this and your goal? Or you want to overwrite the current active sheet with a sheet in the source Spreadsheet?

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm, Much, and Greatly appreciated, thanks for your time..

Comment: @user2912312 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I apologize for my poor English skill.